# Laravel Email Markdown Formatting problems

Tags: markdown, laravel-5.8

First time using `Markdown` in a `Laravel` project and it is not rendering as expected.

Here's my `Markdown`

```
@component('mail::message')

    ![{{ config('app.name') }}][logo]
    [logo]: {{ asset(config('app.vars.logo_small')) }}

    Subscription payment failure!

    @component('mail::table')
    |                  |                                                                            |
    | ---------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
    | Charge:          | {{ $payment->stripe_currency }} {{ $payment->charge_fmt }}                 |
    | Card:            | {{ $payment->stripe_card_brand }}                                          |
    | Last 4:          | {{ '∎∎∎∎ ∎∎∎∎ ∎∎∎∎ ' . $payment->stripe_card_last4 }}                     |
    | Expiry:          | {{ $payment->stripe_card_exp_month }}/{{ $payment->stripe_card_exp_year }} |
    | Description:     | {{ $payment->stripe_description }}                                         |
    @endcomponent


    We tried to bill your subscription but were unable due to unavailable funds.
@endcomponent
```

But it renders like this:

```
LOGOIMG

Subscription payment failure!

<div class="table">
Charge:         usd $10.42
Card:           mastercard
Last 4:         ∎∎∎∎ ∎∎∎∎ ∎∎∎∎ 4444
Expiry:         4/2044
Description:    App Data plan - Regular - 28/04/2019-28/05/2019
We tried to bill your subscription but were unable due to unavailable funds.
```

Why is the `<table>` `HTML` tag showing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/raw-html-showing-in-notification-email). Essentially `PHP Storm` is formatting it on copy n paste, and since it is `Markdown` the spaces are being interpreted.